# Review privilege description error in help center

Tags: bug, meta, help-center, privileges-page

The help center says the following on the review privilege:

[image: 2.000 access review queues - Access first posts and late answers review queues]

But there are no first posts and late answers queues on MSO:

[image: Review/Close Votes/Low Quality Posts/Reopen Votes/Suggested Edits]

Answer (score 2):

From the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/), if you click on the line you have indicated, it takes you to the [help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), which explains:

> Note: These two queues do not exist on [Meta sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

So while what you say is *true*, I'm not sure it is something that requires changing.