# How Are The Reputation Thresholds Decided?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review, privileges

I'm more of a Stack Overflow participant, since I'm a software developer. But, I thought this might be a better question for a general audience of Stack Exchange's sites.

I've been working on giving back to the community that's provided me answers in the past. And, I've found that I kept hitting into full edit queues more often than not:

> Suggested edit queue is full

So, wanting to help out with the queue backlog - I started looking into when I can help with it.

This is when I noticed that Meta Stack Exchange has different reputation requirements for privileges compared to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), e.g.

> Stack Exchange:
> 2000 `access review queues` Access first posts and late answers review queues

> Stack Overflow:
> 500 `access review queues` Access first posts and late answers review queues

And, I hadn't found Q&A that really answered this in a satisfying way. 
How does Stack Exchange's networks decide what their reputation values are set at?

Comment: In general or just for review? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121706/323179

Comment: It's open to general. I chose to explain a specific to be a guiding-line of the conversation.

Comment: The people who run the software decided about them, probably by a mixture of experience, experiments, feedback and gut feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion probably arises from the fact that Meta Stack Exchange doesn't have the two review queues with the lowest level of reputation required: First Posts and Late Answers (despite the [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) saying so; I didn't believe what you wrote but it's [indeed what the page says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212090/295232)). Therefore, the 'access review queues' privilege here is obtained at 2,000, for the Suggested Edits and Low Quality Posts queue. The reputation requirements are the same as on Stack Overflow and other graduated sites with a design.

As for the general procedure, we have three different 'schemas', one for graduated sites with a design, one for public betas and sites without a design, and one for private betas. Some per-site exceptions exist (like the one you asked about) and everything is documented in this FAQ: [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/295232).

*How* these values were derived is a long story; some were chosen in the beginning and just stuck; others were 'reputation milestones' in search of a privilege. You can find some information scattered across various Meta Stack Exchange posts, but no comprehensive list AFAIK.

Comment: As an example, the First Posts and Late Answers review queues were initially unlocked at 125 reputation, the minimum required to take all available actions in that queue, including downvoting. However, later on, the former 500-rep privilege to edit a question's tags without needing to have it approved at a suggested edit was removed, which left a gap at the 500 reputation level, which was fixed by moving the review privilege up to 500.